# HTML/CSS - <p> aligning on the bottom side of <img> in an unexpected way

Tags: html, css

**Reading data from database**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($listOfRecipes)){
      echo '<div class="one_recipe">';
          echo '<div class="recipe_style">';
               echo "<a href=\"project2.php?recipe={$row['RecipeId']}\"><img src=\"{$row['RecipePhoto']}\" class=\"food_img_style\" /></a>";
          echo '</div>';
          echo "<p class=\"recipe_title_style\">{$row['RecipeName']}</p>";
      echo '</div>';
}
```

**style.css**

```
        .one_recipe{
            margin-right: 44px;
            margin-left: 35px;
            display:inline-block;
            text-align:left;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .recipe_style{
            display:inline-block;
            padding: 3px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 1px;
            background: #ECF0F1;
            z-index: 3;
        }

        img.food_img_style{
            max-width: 200px;
            max-height: 200px;
            width: 160px;
            height: 180px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        p.recipe_title_style{
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 5px;
            width: 160px;
        }
```

**Result**

[image: Unexpected Result]

I was trying to align a `<p>` tag on the bottom side of image, but as you see the picture above, it covers the area of `<img>` and pushes it out. Is there a way to make their alignment vertically same, even though the content's width of `<p>` is longer than 160px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions here:

1. Add `vertical-align: top` to `.recipe_style` rule. Thus it will be aligned to the top instead of bottom.
2. "Ellipsize" the text in `.recipe_title_style`:

   ```
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   ```

First one is simplier, but ff you have more than 3 items to display in a grid, I would prefer 2nd one, however it's a bit more complex and assumes your images are always of the same size.

Comment: @MyNameIsAsker you are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Database query while foreach loop**

```
<?php
  $data = array();
  // $listOfRecipes = db....
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($listOfRecipes)){
     $data[] = $row;
  }
?>

<div class="one_recipe">

  <?php foreach ($data as $recipes) { ?>
    <div class="recipe_style">
      <a href="project2.php?recipe=<?php echo $recipes['RecipeId']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $recipes['RecipePhoto']; ?>" class="food_img_style" /></a>
      <p class="recipe_title_style"><?php echo $recipes['RecipeName']; ?></p> **// p class title div before**
    </div>
  <?php } ?>

</div>
```

**at look css fix**

```
    .recipe_style{
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 3px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background: #ECF0F1;
        z-index: 3;
        vertical-align: top; // fixer upper
    }

    img.food_img_style{
     // max-width: 200px;
     // max-height: 200px;
        width: 160px!important; // !important class fixed image
        height: 180px!important;// !important class fixed image
        padding: 0px;
        top:0;
    }

    p.recipe_title_style{
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 160px;
        overflow: hidden; // text lenght to width 160px last hidden
    }
```